# Java Enum Default Explicit Constructor not Defined

Tags: java, enums

I guarantee you this will be a very stupid question, but I am having a brain block and can not figure out how to fix this error. I am working in Java and trying to define a Enum.

`public enum ShooterStatus{
        OFF,EXTENDING,CONTRACTING,LOADED
    }`

This enum is defined within another class. When compiling, I get the following error:

`Implicit super constructor Enum(String, int) is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor`

What am I missing here? Shouldn't an enum declaration just be that? (I am used to programming in C)

Containing class:

```
package org.usfirst.frc3777;

import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.DoubleSolenoid;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.SpeedController;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.Timer;

public class Shooter {

    public enum ShooterStatus{
        OFF,EXTENDED,CONTRACTING,LOADED
    }

    SpeedController upperCont;
    SpeedController lowerCont;
    DoubleSolenoid dS;

    Boolean isLoaded;
    Boolean isRunning;

    Timer mainTimer;

    DoubleSolenoid.Value extend = DoubleSolenoid.Value.kForward;
    DoubleSolenoid.Value compress = DoubleSolenoid.Value.kReverse;
    DoubleSolenoid.Value off = DoubleSolenoid.Value.kOff;

    String label = "Shooter";

    private boolean wheelsRunning(){
        return upperCont.get()>.5&&lowerCont.get()>.5;
    }

    public Shooter(SpeedController upperCont, SpeedController lowerCont, DoubleSolenoid dS){
        this.upperCont = upperCont;
        this.lowerCont = lowerCont;
        this.dS = dS;
    }

    private void setExtendPiston(){
        dS.set(extend);
    }

    private void setCompressPiston(){
        dS.set(compress);
    }

    private void setOffPiston(){
        dS.set(off);
    }

    public boolean startShootingThread(){
        if(!isLoaded){
            Log.info(label, "Shooter is not currently loaded in logic");
            return false;
        }
        if(isRunning){
            Log.info(label, "Shooter is currently running");
            return false;
        }
        setExtendPiston();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the complete `enum` definition? Sure you're not missing anything else here?

Comment: This doesn't look like complete code.. you can show other class ?

Comment: That is the whole Enum definition. If im missing something please speak up. Ive been researching this for awhile now and I'm not sure. Again I am used to using C, so Java may be different. If you want downvote this for stupidity, but I'm truely at a loss for what this enum needs.

Comment: @JoeIsI As sanbhat said, please paste the code of the enclosing class. According to you, "This enum is defined within another class". We need the "another class"!

Comment: Added the entire class.

Comment: @JoeIsI Strange - your code compiles nicely for me. What version of Java are you using and on what platform?

Comment: Looking at the link fvrghl gave, I did have a semicolon after LOADED . I removed it, but the error persists. Looking again at the link, my Enum definition looks like it shouldn't be throwing this error.

Comment: @JoeIsI This is massive stab in the dark, but what happens if you declare the enum as static? Ie: `public static enum ShooterStatus{ OFF,EXTENDING,CONTRACTING,LOADED; }`

Comment: Problem solved: I never defined a JDK. I am using an odd configuration to program FRC robots (www.usfirst.org) and it did not define the default JDK like my default configuration. Thanks to Muel for pointing out to check the Java version.

Comment: So using an rt.jar of a pre-1.5 JRE, which doesn't have `java.lang.Enum`, or something?

Comment: No I wasn't using a rt.jar at all. I never defined a JDK to use and therefore never loaded the rt.jar.

Comment: hay, OP, juz restart your IDE. My error disappeared juz by doing this.

Comment: It's your JRE/JDK, try another version.

Answer (score -3):

Get rid of the semicolon.  Go from this:

```
public enum ShooterStatus{ OFF,EXTENDING,CONTRACTING,LOADED; }
```

to this:

```
public enum ShooterStatus{ OFF,EXTENDING,CONTRACTING,LOADED }
```

More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

You should also check if you ever defined a default JDK.

Comment: If the semicolon is after the last enum value there won't be any problem.

Comment: Its quite strange, I removed and put the semicolon again, and it was working!

Comment: The semicolon is correct, removing it and adding it forces it to rebuild - MrParrot 8 years too late